# program for developing eclipse plugin to parse a java program

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I am a Java developer and I use Eclipse as an IDE. I tend to write several methods in a Java program, but when it comes to loggers, I don't add any. Is there any way I can develop a plugin for Eclipse that would parse through the entire Java class and identify the method beginning and end and then added entry loggers and exit loggers? Other than using text parsing, is there any way to identify the beginning and end of a method?

Comment: The question lacks detail and motivation, but this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086127/java-is-it-possible-to-automatically-add-log-statements-to-methods

Comment: Transparently add a crosscutting concern such as logging to your program? Sounds like what AOP is made for. Maybe you would like to take a look at [AspectJ](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/index.php)

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this with an [Aspect-Oriented](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/aspect-oriented-programming-spring-aop.html) approach.  There is an example of logging in that article.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution, if you're using Spring or aspect oriented programming, would be to weave in a logging aspect.